# How to show this function Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$Q)$ Let $h(x)=0$ for $\forall x \in A$ with $\bar A = I(=[0,1])$. Show $\int_I h dx =0$

(Here the $A$ is a closure of the $A(\subset I)$)

I decided to use Riemann's method that $\vert U(h,P) - L(h,P) \vert \lt \epsilon$ for refinement $P$

So I took the refinement, $P = \{x_0(=0),...,x_n(=1)\}$

Plus Since $\bar A = I(=[0,1])$, $\exists  a_k \in [x_k, x_{k+1}] s.t. a_k \in A$ for each interval $I_k = [x_k, x_{k+1}]$ ($0\leq k \leq n-1$)

Therefore, $\vert L(h,P_n) \vert = \vert \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} inf\{h(x) \vert x \in I_k \} \Delta x_k \vert \lt \epsilon$(I.e.$\vert L(h,P_n) \vert \lt \epsilon $ )

So all I have to do left is showing  $\vert U(h,P_n) \vert \lt \epsilon $(or $\lim_{n\to \infty} U(h,P_n) =0$) What should I next to prove that?

p.s.) If my process is incorrect any another method always welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The questions makes no sense, since $h(x)$ is not known , if $x \in I \setminus A.$

Example: Let $A:= [0,1] \cap( \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q),$ and $h$ be defined by

$h(x)=0$ , if $x \in A$ and $h(x)=1$, if $x \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q.$

It is well-known that $h$ is not Riemann integrable.